# How are parameters passed to URL in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm wondering how parameters are appended to the request URL. Let's say I have a form with some links:

[image]

When I click 'Edit' for Steve I got the following URL:

[image]

with '3' as StudentID appended on the end of URL. How does it happen?

I check my RouteConfig:

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Student",
                url: "student/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Index"}
            );


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

{id} next to 'student/' can be replaced with anything, the name doesn't matter here.

I check my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestAPP.Models.Student>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.StudentId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.StudentId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.StudentId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }


</table>
```

Even though I can see 'StudentId' item assigned to 'Edit' link (shown on the bottom of my code) I have no clue if it's here where 'Id' parameter is appended to URL somehow when I'm clicking 'Edit'

Comment: Yes that's where it happens. The ActionLink method you're calling constructs the URL from the data you give it

Comment: does it matter if parameter in routing (here it's {id}) has the same name as parameter in razor (here: new id = ...)?

Comment: Change the name of the routing parameter and give it a try, then you'll find out! (Or change the name of the parameter in your action method, either way you'll see)

Comment: I change the name of routing parameter to 'ide' but parameter for razor remained 'id' and it works. So those parameteres don't correspond to each other (their names). I still don't understand dependecy bewteen those two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.StudentId })
```

Creates the url associated with the edit page of each 'item'. `@Html.ActionLink` is a directive to the razor page library that executes a function concatenating arguments to a url string. the `new { id = item.StudentId }` provides route values to the function as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LinkExtensions_ActionLink_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_Object_). Your router expects an optional `{id}` parameter for routing to a specific resource and it looks for this value at the end of the uri.

Comment: ok, so everytime I'll make some assigment like ```new { id = item.StudentId }``` for a razor then it's a signal for compilator that I want to append some value at the end of uri, right?

Comment: Essentially yes. The parameters you are using in ActionLink are: linkText: string which identifies the tag,  actionName: string which points to a specific action for the controller to execute, and routeValues: object, string, or dictionary which includes route values like 'id'. So you have a uri of `https://example.com/student/1?action=edit` and the method called within your controller is 'Edit' which likely loads the edit page. When creating the 'Edit" page for a single student, the `{id}` value maps to the razor page declaration of `@page "{id:int}"`